# Updating the presentation of a credit card field as the card type becomes known

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, e-commerce

The goal here is to, add a credit card image, and remove all other credit card images, of a certain input field.
I had a even larger code, with a lot of addClass() and removeClass()... then, I shrink it until I have this.
Still, I feel it's still a huge block of code.

The point here is to short things up, but NOT until it's hard to understand what's going on.

```
if (event.isValid) {

    if (event.card.type == 'visa') {

        $("#card-number").addClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST.replace(CREDIT_CARD_LIST, 'e-visa'));

    } else if (event.card.type == 'master-card') {

        $("#card-number").addClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST.replace(CREDIT_CARD_LIST, 'e-master-card'));

    } else if (event.card.type == 'e-american-express') {

        $("#card-number").addClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST.replace(CREDIT_CARD_LIST, 'e-american-express'));

    } else if (event.card.type == 'diners-club') {

        $("#card-number").addClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST.replace(CREDIT_CARD_LIST, 'e-diners-club'));

    } else if (event.card.type == 'discover') {

        $("#card-number").addClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST.replace(CREDIT_CARD_LIST, 'e-discover'));

    } else if (event.card.type == 'jcb') {

        $("#card-number").addClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST.replace(CREDIT_CARD_LIST, 'e-jcb'));

    } else if (event.card.type == 'unionpay') {

        $("#card-number").addClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST.replace(CREDIT_CARD_LIST, 'e-unionpay'));

    } else if (event.card.type == 'maestro') {

        $("#card-number").addClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST.replace(CREDIT_CARD_LIST, 'e-maestro'));
    }

} else {

    $("#card-number").removeClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST);
}
```

Comment: Is `} else if (event.card.type == 'e-american-express') {` a typo in that it should be `== 'american-express'`.

Comment: I don't understand CREDIT_CARD_LIST.replace(CREDIT_CARD_LIST, 'e-visa') wouldn't it be the same as just adding 'e-visa' ?

Answer (score 5):

Create a map from `card.type` to what class it should be:

```
var cardTypeToClass = {  'visa': 'e-visa',
                         'master-card': 'e-master-card',
                         //...
                       };
```

This creates an associative array so if you give it a key value then you can get out the associated value.

in your case that is done like:

```
if (event.isValid) {
    $("#card-number").addClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST.replace(CREDIT_CARD_LIST, cardTypeToClass[event.card.type]));
} else {
    $("#card-number").removeClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST);
}
```

This concentrates the mapping into a single section and separates out what the code actually does.

Comment: I don't understand how "cardTypeToClass[event.card.type]" will know what kind it is that we have to show. Care to explain a little further?

Comment: I would extract a variable: `var cardType = cardTypeToClass[event.card.type]; $("#card-number").addClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST.replace(CREDIT_CARD_LIST, cardType));`

Answer (score 4):

It seems the value you're trying to replace for is really just the `event.card.type` prefixed by `e-`, so just string concatenate them together.

***However***, if some of the replace variables do *not* follow this pattern, it'd be best to use @ratchet freak's solution.

```
if (event.isValid) {
    $("#card-number").addClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST.replace(CREDIT_CARD_LIST, 'e-' + event.card.type));
} else {
    $("#card-number").removeClass(CREDIT_CARD_LIST);
}
```

Comment: `e-american-express` doesn't follow the pattern

Comment: That looks like a typo though.

Comment: If it doesn't follow the pattern, you should strongly consider _making_ it follow the pattern rather than accommodating special cases.